# Simular click no WebBrowser usando C#

Tags: c#

Queria saber como faço para realizar um *click* sobre um elemento de um site (no final), gostaria de que ele clicasse sobre esse elemento.

```
href="javascript:;" class="spot drugdealer" title="Traficante de drogas"
```

ja tentei usar o `.GetAttribute()`, junto com o `InvokeMember("click")` mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Olá. Quando no titulo refere webbrowser, fala do seu navegador ou da classe `WebBrowser`?

Comment: falo do navegador que podemos adicionar na nossa form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que você esteja utilizando a classe `WebBrowser`. Se o elemento que você quer clicar conter um `id` você pode simular um click desse modo:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

As informações fornecidas por você não citaram se há algum `id` ou não, apenas a classe `spot drugdealer`, para simular um click em um elemento através de sua classe, faça:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "spot drugdealer")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: MUITOOOOOOOO OBRIGADO SOU MUITO AGRADECIDO.