# Simular um Click no WebBrowser utilizando C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Queria saber como faço para realizar um click em um botão de um site da internet mesmo, clicando assim sobre tal elemento web depurado no proprio browser.

Estou a utilizar o componente webbrowser do C#

Já tentei alguns métodos aqui, porém sem sucesso, mesmo utilizando GetElementsByTagName

e no html do site está desse jeito.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="confirmarPresenca()">ENTRADA</button>
```

Tentei com o seguinte código mas sem sucesso na minha Windows Form Application C#

```
HtmlElementCollection el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach(HtmlElement btn in el)
{
    if(btn.GetAttribute("type").Equals("button")
    {
         btn.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: qual versão do asp.net vc está utilizando? É webforms ou MVC?

Comment: por favor especifique melhor o seu contexto, é utilizando o componente WebBrowser do C# ou é em um browser da web?

Comment: Na minha resposta, inputei "absolutamente nada a ver com C#" – o que pode ser um equívoco. Vendo a nomenclatura que ele usou (WebBrowser + C#), parece tanto com WebForms – que eu nunca trabalhei. Estou no aguardo de uma atualização dele para ir adiante.

Comment: Seria um componente webbrowser do c#.
Olha um exemplo de link de como seria mais ou menos minha duvida, porem a parte do html do site seria igual a que citei em cima

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17003/simular-click-no-webbrowser-usando-c

Comment: Você chegou a depurar o código pra tentar identificar onde exatamente está o problema? Você poderia verificar: (1) se `el` contém algo, (2) o que `GetAttribute("type")` retorna e (3) se esse retorno é igual a `"button"` minúsculo, e compartilhar na pergunta. Iria facilitar um bocado pra que alguém te ajudasse. :)

Comment: Cara não entendi posso estar meio bocó mas seria isso: Você quer clicar em um botão definido no `aspx` por meio do code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Seria no caso clicar em um botão de uma URL especifica da WEB.
O primeiro botão ele tinha a seguinte parte em HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Entrar" name="commit"></input>
```

o código para conseguir efetuar o click neste botão do seguinte modo

```
//Clica no Botão Entrar Após Preenchimento dos Campos
HtmlElementCollection doc1 = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach(HtmlElement doc00 in doc1)
{
    //Opção 2
    if(doc00.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
    {
        doc00.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Porém depois que ele loga na certa URL, que foi preenchido os campos de login e senha, tem outra página que ele entra, contendo o seguinte trecho de código em HTML, que é um botão também e queria invocar um clique nele.

```
<button ng-click="confirmarPresenca()" type="button"></button>
```

Porém como citado acima, já tentei pegando pelo elemento button e atributo e não tive retorno, e queria algum método de eu conseguir invocar um click neste botão de acordo com esse HTML acima

Answer (score 1):

SNOT, você pode usar as APIs `HtmlAgilityPack` ou até `CsQuery`, dentre outras, no seu projeto. Se consultar no NUGET irá encontrá-las.
Elas possibilitam fazer uso de busca CSS para resgatar objetos do DOM.

Mas se no caso você for continuar usando apenas o `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, eu indico usar o `GetElementsByTagName("button")` e por array chegar ao elemento que você deseja executar o click.